# Logstash puts everything into all Elasticsearch indexes

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash, bigdata

I have 4 file under `/etc/logstash/conf.d`. Those 4 files are used for reading tomcat's logs and apache's logs, for listen on port 3456 for log4j and to read CSV file.

Everything works fine but when Logstash parses my CSV file, it puts CSV file's related data into tomcat's logs index, apache's logs index, log4j indexes and CSV file index (as I want).

There is my CSV file's config file:

```
input {
   file {
     path => "/exports/export4hadoop_FULL.csv"
     start_position => "beginning"
     sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
   }
}

filter {
    csv {
      columns => ["idTopic", "idContenu", "typeContenu", "titre", "date", "tag", "message", "typetag", "idGroupTmp"]
      separator => ";"
    }
    ruby {
      code => "
        b = event.get('idGroupTmp').split(',')
        arr = Array.new
        for c in b
            arr.push(c)
        end
        event.set('idGroups', arr)
      "
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "bigdatam1:9200"
    index => "collabore_import"
  }
}
```

I truly specified `"collabore_index"` as index under `"elasticsearch"` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logstash will combine the configuration files into a big one. So, depending on what you have for the other types of logs, you are probably not "separating" correctly the outputs.

```
output {
  if ([type] == "csv") {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => "bigdatam1:9200"
      index => "collabore_import"
    }
  }
}
```

and in the input set the `type` accordingly:

```
input {
   file {
     path => "/exports/export4hadoop_FULL.csv"
     start_position => "beginning"
     sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
     type => "csv"
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works fine ! But I don't understand why other configuration's files works and this one doesn't ..